# Is the space of pairs with addition $(x,y) + (a,b) = (x+a+1,y+b+1)$ a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove the set $S =\{ (x,y) \mid x,y ∈ \mathbb{R} \}$ is a vector space with the operations of vector addition and scalar multiplication.

$$(x,y) + (a,b) = (x+a+1,y+b+1)$$
$$\alpha(x,y) = (\alpha x,\alpha y)$$

I think it is vector space but I am not sure.

Comment: Start by checking if the vector space axioms are satisfied.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$2(x,y) \stackrel{?}{=} (x,y)+(x,y).$$

Comment: Is this a vector space axiom?

Comment: Distributivity of scalar multiplication with respect to field addition is. This is a very specific case of that.

Comment: L.H.S will be (2x+1,2y+1) 
from this it can not be vector space 
I understand it well ?

Comment: The left hand side, by the definitions of the operations you have written, would be $(2x,2y)$. What would the right hand side be?

Comment: I am sorry I mean right hand side will be **(2x+1,2y+1)**